# OOAD - File-Format-Reader class vs Object-Model class: which should depend on which?

Tags: file-io, language-agnostic, dependencies, ooad

Let's consider, as an example, the domain of GPS and Geographical (GIS) entities.

We would model the meaningful geographic entities (points, paths, regions) as classes in any desired programming language, and these classes would be a conceptual, "implementation-free" representation of these entities.

On the other hand, there are a lot of file formats that save these features with more or less the same meaning. In the GPS domain the most common file formats are GPX, KML, ShapeFile, WellKnownText, etc.

Supposing, then, I want to create a `GpsFeatureCollection` class which would contain a `Points` property, a `Paths` property, and so on. Also, I would implement classes like `GpsReader`, `KmlReader`, `ShapeFileReader` (and their respective `Writer`s) and so on.

THE QUESTION IS:

Which is the best practice in OOAD:

1. Have a `GpsFeatureCollection` to instantiate a `FileFormat(Reader/Writer)` class?
2. Have a `GpsFeatureCollection` to implement `Read/WriteFromFormat` methods instead of classes?
3. Have each file format reader to instantiate an empty `GpsFeatureCollection`, populate it with data read from file, then pass the populated object as a return value?
4. Have a mediator class to avoid any dependency between `FileFormatClass` and `ObjectModelClass`?
5. None of the above?
6. "Well, it depends..."

I am really interested in doing "the right thing". My immediate plans are to use Python, but most probably this would matter for other languages too. This is causing some "analysis paralysis" in my pet project currently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take wherein I pass reader and writer instances to `read()` and `write()` methods, this seems to achieve good level of decoupling and yet provides flexibility to pick various readers and writers.

Code uses Java-like syntax

Declare a `Reader` interface, we will assuming multiple implementation such `KMLReader`, 
`ShapeFileReader`, etc

```
interface Reader {
   GpsFeatureCollection read();
}
```

Declare a `Writer` interface, we will assuming multiple implementation such `KMLWriter`, `ShapeFileWriter`, etc

```
interface Writer {
   void write(GpsFeatureCollection c);
}
```

Let's declare `GpsFeatureCollection` class to have `read` and `write` methods which accept respective interfaces as parameter to perform the job.

```
class GpsFeatureCollection {

    ...

    public static GpsFeatureCollection read(Reader r) {
       return r.read();
    } 

    public static void write(Writer w) { 
        w.write(this);
    }

}
```

Some example of usage using different readers and writers.

```
// Reading data
GpsFeaureCollection data = GpsFeatureCollection.read(new ShapeFileReader("/tmp/shapefile"));

// Writing data
data.write(new KMLWriter("/tmp/kmlfile"));
```

Comment: This is pure gold! Thank you very much. As an only suggestion, I would name the interfaces IReader and IWriter (but not IGpsFeatureCollectionReader, etc. :P ). Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that you liked it.  Java-folks don't use prefix "I" for interface, though I don't mind if one uses it as long as it is consistently used.

Comment: As a side note (now that I had lunch and my brain is working again), another possible design would be to have, say, a `GpxFormat` class, with `read` and `write` methods to be used by the common interface. Then, the same class could implement a lot of boilerplate/specification-specific code that would most probably be reused by the IO methods, and the `FileFormat` class would be sort of just a file handler passed as arguments to either method.